# Printing with Heidelberg CMYK Explained

Tags: color, print-design

I need to print a brochure on a `CMYK heidelberg CPC` printing machine.

The design house has asked me this: "We'll need to know that/if you are using a specific profile for uncoated paper. Right now the pictures have `FOGRA29` embedded for uncoated paper. Is that okay for you?"

I actually don't know what this means... I don't know what `FOGRA29` is, all I know is my machine can print `CMYK`.

Can someone please explain what it all means?

Comment: "Is that okay for you?" = you need to ask the design house, not us.

Answer (score 4):

**Your answer is "Yes, that will be fine."**

- FOGRA39 Coated
- FOGRA27 Coated (lightweight)
- FOGRA29 Uncoated

You'll see that the CMYK working space for the document on uncoated stock is FOGRA29.

EDIT > Color Settings > Working Spaces CMYK: Uncoated FOGRA29.

Don't alter the correct setting. Good Luck.

Note: The RIP will take care of any necessary conversions.

Answer (score 2):

FOGRA29 is a special color scheme. You need to prepare Adobe InDesign or ... to use this color scheme.

In English: Go to `Edit` > `Color Settings...` then under `Working Spaces` there's a `CMYK` menu for `Uncoated FOGRA29`.

In German:
Change in menu `Bearbeiten` –- `Farbeinstellungen...` the `Arbeitsfarbräume` for `CMYK` to `FOGRA29 ... uncoated` and click on `Ok`.

You can also use Adobe Preflight to change the color management to FOGRA29.

Comment: Fogra39 is not a color scheme. It is a color profile. You do not need to prepare any program to use it, you need to have it installed.